# Django: Access related object attributes from a form field in a template?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm building a page that allows users to edit Task and related Activity records (one task can have many activities), all on the same page.  Here are extracts from my code...

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Task(models.Model):
    category    = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Activity(models.Model):
    task  = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

The activity "owner" is linked to a `User` from the Django standard user model.

**views.py**

```
def manage_task(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(pk = pk)
    TaskInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Task, Activity, 
        form = ActivityForm)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instance = task)
        formset = TaskInlineFormSet(request.POST, instance = task)
        if form.has_changed() and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        if formset.has_changed() and formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
        return redirect('manage_task',pk=task.id)
    else:
        form = TaskForm(instance = task)
        formset = TaskInlineFormSet(instance = task)
    context = {'task': task, 'task_form': form, 'formset': formset}
    return render(request, 'tasks/manage_task.html', context)
```

And **manage_task.html** excerpt:

```
<h2>{{ task.category }}</h2>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ task_form.description }}
    {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.id }}
        {{ form.title }}</br>
        {{ form.notes }}</br>
        {% if user.id == form.owner.value %}
            You own this Activity!</br>
        {% else %}
            {{ form.owner.first_name }} owns this Activity</br>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="save" type="submit" value="SAVE">
</form>
```

Perhaps obviously, `{{ form.owner.first_name }}` doesn't return anything.  `form.owner` understandably renders as a select drop down with all the Users listed - it's some sort of iterable object so it doesn't have a `first_name` attribute.

I think I need to have the first_name field in each form in the formset so it ties up properly with the correct Activity form.

I feel like I might have to adapt the view in some way to go through all the forms in the formset and use the owner.id (if it exists) to access the related User and add the first_name attribute as an extra field in the form somehow?  That doesn't feel very Djangoish, there must be a better way.

How can I use the form field `form.owner` to get the first_name attribute from the User object that's related to the Activity so I can use it in the template?

Comment: You can try `form.instance.owner.first_name`. It should work, but be aware of one drawback: if user changes `owner` on the page from A to B, submits the form and then validation fails, `form.instance.owner` will remain old (A) on returned page, as form was not saved.

Comment: Thanks @SUTerliakov.  Appreciate the warning.  In this instance I'm just trying to display the name so I don't think there will be an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not take such value from `form` directly. It may be risky (i.e. changing real-life). But if you are aware of it and ok with that, try pointing to specific instance of `form`:

```
{{ form.instance.owner.first_name }}
```